# AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to make test for model `rake test`
and I got this error,

> AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter

my `database.yml` spec is:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: adel_development
 encoding: utf8
 pool: 5
 username: root
 timeout: 5000
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: adel_development
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
```

what's going on any help

note: I was using `qlite3` and changed to `mysql2`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a test environment in your `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: adel_test
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  timeout: 5000
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

You'll then need to create this database `adel_test` and to launch `rake db:test:prepare`